# Can I tell if an abstract method has been called?

Tags: java, design-patterns, reflection, abstract-methods

Given this class:

```
abstract class Foo{
    public Foo(){...}

    public abstract void checkable();

    public void calledWhenCheckableIsCalled(){
        System.out.println("checkable was called");
    }
}
```

Is there any code I can put in Foo's constructor to make `calledWhenCheckableIsCalled` get called when `checkable` is called?

Note: This is a gross simplification of an actual project I am working on.

Edit: I have already implemented a template pattern workaround. I just wondered if there was another way to do this I am missing. (Perhaps using reflection.)

Comment: @BrianRoach Sigh, I was pretty sure this wouldn't work. It would make the functionality I want a lot easier to implement.

Comment: The only way you know  `checkable()` is called is by putting some code inside it. Or create wrapper method around it.

Comment: Can't think of a way you could do that like you're asking, but you could check if it was called during a unit test with various mocking frameworks, ie `Mockito` or `JMockit`.

Comment: I mean, you could make it protected and call it by a public proxy method in your abstract class ... but that's all I got.

Comment: I already have implemented a workaround, but this would of made my code a little more elegant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like a [template method pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern).

But then you must implement `Foo.checkable()` and introduce another abstract method to delegate to.

```
abstract class Foo{
    public Foo(){}

    public void checkable(){
        calledWhenCheckableIsCalled();            
        doCheckable();
    } 

    protected abstract void doCheckable();

    public void calledWhenCheckableIsCalled(){
        System.out.println("checkable was called");
    }
}
```

I would also suggest to make `checkable()` final in this case so that you can be sure that `checkable()` can not implemented in another way as you expected.

**In addition to Brian Roach's comment**

> The downside is that the protected can be expanded to public in the subclass, so you can't explicitly enforce it.

That's true, but you can prevent a `Foo` instance from being instantiated if a subclass increases the visibility of `doCheckable`. Therefore you have to introduce a verification whenever an object is instantiated. I would recommend to use an initializer code so that the verification is executed on every constructor that exists. Then it can not be forgotten to invoke and therefore be by-passed.

For example:

```
abstract class Foo {
    { // instance initializer code ensures that enforceDoCheckableVisibility
      // is invoked for every constructor
        enforceDoCheckableVisibility();
    }
    public Foo() {...}
    public Foo(Object o) {...}

    private void enforceDoCheckableVisibility() {
        Class<?> currentClass = getClass();
        while (currentClass != Foo.class) {
            try {
                Method doCheckableMethod = currentClass.getDeclaredMethod("doCheckable");
                if (Modifier.isPublic(doCheckableMethod.getModifiers())) {
                    throw new RuntimeException("Visibility of "
                                  + currentClass.getSimpleName()
                                  + ".doCheckable() must not be public");
                }
            } catch (SecurityException | NoSuchMethodException e) {}
            currentClass = currentClass.getSuperclass();
        }
    }
}
```

Since the check is implemented using reflection the downside is that it is only checked at runtime. So you will not have compiler support of course. But this approach let you enforce that an instance of a `Foo` can only exist if it fulfills your contract.

Comment: +1 - this is what I was getting at in my comment. The downside is that the `protected` can be expanded to `public` in the subclass, so you can't explicitly enforce it.

Comment: @BrianRoach yes you're right. I only see one way to prevent subclasses from increasing the visibility by using a reflection check in the constructor. I updated my answer. What do you think?

Comment: Heh, that's certainly a way to enforce it :) I'd upvote you again if I could.

Comment: @BrianRoach yes. I mean that the compiler can't enforce it. Maybe not clear. I think about it and update. :)

Answer (score 2):

No, the constructor will get invoked once during the object initialisation. You can however get your subclass that provides the implementation to call the method in the super class:

```
class Bar extends Foo {

    // implementation of abstract method
    public void checkable(){
        super.calledWhenCheckableIsCalled(); // call to parent's method
        ...
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

You could achieve this with aspects. Using an aspect you can intercept each call to a method by referring to the abstract parent method. This leaves you free from interfering eith the child code. Your `calledWhenCheckableIsCalled` code would then become part of the intercepting code.

```
abstract class Foo {

    // use pointcut to intercept here
    public void checkable();
}
```

Comment: I see how this would work, but I don't really want to get switch over to using AspectJ.

Answer (score 0):

There is no  way as you are forcing that method to implement in `child`.

An  awkward  suggestion will be know from child implementation. I mean there is no clean way *AFAIK*

Answer (score 0):

```
abstract class foo {

    public abstract void bar();

    public void moo() {
        System.out.println("some code");

        this.bar();

        System.out.println("more code");
    }
}
```

now if `moo` is called, the underlying implementation of `bar` will be used, it is just a small paradigm shift from what you want.

so your end user would call `moo` instead of `bar`, but he still needs to implement `bar`

Answer (score 0):

Nope, an abstract method doesn't have a body. You could, however, chain your method like this:

```
abstract class Foo {

    void callMeInstead() {

        // do common

        callMeImplementation();
    }

    abstract void callMeImplementation();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you're looking for the template pattern:

```
public abstract class Template {
    public final void checkable() {
        calledWhenCheckableIsCalled();
        doCheckable();
    }

    protected abstract void doCheckable();

    private  void calledWhenCheckableIsCalled() {
        System.out.println("checkable was called");
    }
}
```

Now, each time `checkable()` is called, `calledWhenCheckableIsCalled()` is also called. And the suclass must still provide the actual implementation of `checkable()`, by implementing the `doCheckable()` method.

Note that making `checkable()` final prevents a subclass from overriding it and thus bypassing the call to `calledWhenCheckableIsCalled()`.